# MySQL multiple sum table

Tags: mysql

from the following fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f1d2/5  I want to sum crossing table as the query below, but i got trouble with duplicate value of sale_event. do you have any idea about it.

```
SELECT
 a.province_id,
 SUM(a.sale_event) AS sale_eventTotal,
 SUM(d.order_fullpay) AS order_fullpayTotal
FROM
    san_activites a
LEFT JOIN
    sale_event_detail d
ON
    a.san_activity_id = d.san_activity_id
WHERE 
    a.entry_date BETWEEN '2014-7-1' AND '2014-7-30'
GROUP BY a.province_id
```

Comment: What result do you expect then?

Comment: hm... if you look detail at the insert row... I would expected on province_id 2 should have sale_event only 4 not 8 which it is a duplicate value

Comment: You seem to have duplicate rows in your data. Are you saying you want to ignore duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the results I think you're wanting below. the result brings back 
3 | 10 
4 | 20

```
SELECT 
 SUM(a.sale_event) AS sale_eventTotal,
 SUM(d.order_fullpayTotal) AS order_fullpayTotal
FROM
    san_activites a
LEFT JOIN
    (select SUM(order_fullpay) AS order_fullpayTotal, san_activity_id from sale_event_detail group by san_activity_id) d
ON
    a.san_activity_id = d.san_activity_id
WHERE 
    a.entry_date BETWEEN '2014-7-1' AND '2014-7-30'
GROUP BY a.province_id
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f1d2/49)

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `GROUP BY a.province_id` and run the query it worked for me.

Comment: Hm... I need that group by province friend.

Answer (score 0):

Either [add a unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql) on `san_activity_id`, or dedupe at query time:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(a.sale_event) AS sale_eventTotal,
 SUM(d.order_fullpay) AS order_fullpayTotal
FROM
    san_activites a
LEFT JOIN
    (select * from sale_event_detail group by san_activity_id) d
ON
    a.san_activity_id = d.san_activity_id
WHERE 
    a.entry_date BETWEEN '2014-7-1' AND '2014-7-30'
GROUP BY a.province_id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f1d2/14)

Comment: Hi friend really thanks for your help. You almost right but just on the order_fullpay I would expected for 20. Thank you very much.